# Index based on dates

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Date_Filed Form_Type
  <date>     <chr>    
1 2000-03-24 10-K     
2 2000-01-27 10-K     
3 2000-03-16 10-Q     
4 2000-03-21 10-K     
5 2000-03-21 10-K     
6 2000-03-21 10-K
```

I want to add an index like this:

```
Date_Filed Form_Type Index
  <date>     <chr>   <Int>
1 2000-03-24 10-K     -3 
2 2000-01-27 10-K     -2
3 2000-03-16 10-Q     -1
4 2000-03-21 10-K      0
5 2000-03-21 10-K      1
6 2000-03-21 10-K      3
```

The problem is that the index should be 0 for any date I give a function, with a positive index for dates in the future and negative for dates in the past (where 0 is the present). The number of rows in the data frame may differ. Does any one have a good solution for this?

tidyverse / dplyr solution is preferable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does the index skip from 1 to 3 in rows 5 and 6?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match your stated problem. Rows 4-6 all have a date of March 21, but have ascending indices. Rows 1-3 seem randomly ordered. What guarantee is there that a "past" date won't slip into the "future" section?

Answer (score 0):

Below I defined a function `rank_date`. Is this what you are looking for? Note that I changed the example data to better reflect the problem you described. Further, you would need to think of how to treat ties. You can just specify the `ties.method` as described in  `?rank`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Date_Filed = as.Date(c("2000-03-24",
                                  "2000-01-27",
                                  "2000-03-16",
                                  "2000-03-21",
                                  "2000-03-22",
                                  "2000-03-23")),
           `Form_Type` = c("10-K", "10-K", "10-Q", "10-K", "10-K", "10-K")
)
 

rank_date <- function(x, anker, ties.method = "average") {
  diff <- as.numeric(x - as.Date(anker))
  ini_rank <- rank(diff, ties.method = ties.method)
  ref <- ini_rank[x == anker][1]
  out_rank <- ini_rank - ref
  out_rank
}

library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Index = rank_date(Date_Filed, "2000-03-21"))

#>   Date_Filed Form_Type Index
#> 1 2000-03-24      10-K     3
#> 2 2000-01-27      10-K    -2
#> 3 2000-03-16      10-Q    -1
#> 4 2000-03-21      10-K     0
#> 5 2000-03-22      10-K     1
#> 6 2000-03-23      10-K     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This might be a solution